# How to get a brieflist file on my iPhone and run it

Tags: iphone, mocking, mockups

I'm testing mockup software Briefs (giveabrief.com) and managed to 'compile' one of the examples into a .brieflist file.
Can anyone explain the next step, how to get the file on my iphone and how to run it.

I have purchased DiskAid to access files on my iPhone but dont know what to do.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

--- update ---

Ok, i now understand i have to get the Briefs application running on my iPhone. I've just started playing with xCode, having a hard time understanding the provisioning system...

I downloaded the code for the Briefs app (https://github.com/capttaco/Briefs). Can anyone hint me how to open a existing project in xCode?

Comment: What file you want to get from your iPhone .brieflist ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it on the simulator first, this will avoid the whole code signing issue until you are signed up for Apple's dev program.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read documentation: [**Introduction**](http://giveabrief.com/docs/index.html), [**Building Briefs**](http://giveabrief.com/docs/build.html), [**Briefcasts & Sharing**](http://giveabrief.com/docs/share.html)

Copy onto a Web Server (or Dropbox public folder)
**In order to load the .brieflist into Briefs, you must first copy that onto a web-accessible location.** You can use any server you wish, but if you have a Dropbox account it’s simple. Just copy the .brieflist into your Public folder, then right click that file and select “Copy Public Link” from the Dropbox menu. [Continue reading ...](http://giveabrief.com/docs/share.html)

**I think you can run it using Brifs application !**

Good luck ...